# Converting a theano model built on GPU to CPU?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, pickle, theano

I have some pickle files of deep learning models built on gpu. I'm trying to use them in production. But when i try to unpickle them on the server, i'm getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "score.py", line 30, in 
>       model = (cPickle.load(file))
>     File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py", line 485, in CudaNdarray_unpickler
>       return cuda.CudaNdarray(npa)
>   AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CudaNdarray'", , (array([[ 0.011515  ,  0.01171047,  0.10408644, ..., -0.0343636 ,
>            0.04944979, -0.06583775],
>          [-0.03771918,  0.080524  , -0.10609912, ...,  0.11019105,
>           -0.0570752 ,  0.02100536],
>          [-0.03628891, -0.07109226, -0.00932018, ...,  0.04316209,
>            0.02817888,  0.05785328],
>          ...,
>          [ 0.0703947 , -0.00172865, -0.05942701, ..., -0.00999349,
>            0.01624184,  0.09832744],
>          [-0.09029484, -0.11509365, -0.07193922, ...,  0.10658887,
>            0.17730837,  0.01104965],
>          [ 0.06659461, -0.02492988,  0.02271739, ..., -0.0646857 ,
>            0.03879852,  0.08779807]], dtype=float32),))

I checked for that cudaNdarray package in my local machine and it is not installed, but still i am able to unpickle them. But in the server, i am unable to. How do i make them to run on a server which doesnt have a GPU?

Answer (score 4):

There is a script in pylearn2 which may do what you need:

`pylearn2/scripts/gpu_pkl_to_cpu_pkl.py`

Comment: This script is very experimental and has shown to not work properly in many cases. I wonder if there is a better way to tackle this issue.

Comment: There probably is, but no one has done it yet. In theory, you could pull the weights out and convert the graph structure to it's "paired" CPU ops, but this would not be easy.

Answer (score 2):

The related Theano code is [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py).

From there, it looks like there is an option `config.experimental.unpickle_gpu_on_cpu` which you could set and which would make `CudaNdarray_unpickler` return the underlying raw Numpy array.

Comment: Is this included in Theano by default? I mean, is it just a matter of setting this option, and then Cuda arrays are converted transparently?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Note: this doesn't work unless the following environment variable is set: `export THEANO_FLAGS='device=cpu'`

```
import os
from pylearn2.utils import serial
import pylearn2.config.yaml_parse as yaml_parse

if __name__=="__main__":

_, in_path, out_path = sys.argv
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS']="device=cpu"

model = serial.load(in_path)

model2 = yaml_parse.load(model.yaml_src)
model2.set_param_values(model.get_param_values())

serial.save(out_path, model2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just saving the parameters W & b, but not the whole model. You can save the parameters use this:http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loading_and_saving.html?highlight=saving%20load#robust-serialization
This can save the CudaNdarray to numpy array. Then you need to read the params by numpy.load(), and finally convert the numpy array to tensorSharedVariable use theano.shared().