# Theano - NameError: name 'register_gpu_opt' is not defined

Tags: python, gpu, pickle, theano

I have trained a Theano model on a GPU and now want to set it up to run on a server (with no GPU).

First I faced the problem that my model could not be unpickled, due to the missing `CudaNdarray` type. Then, following a recommendation from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237039/converting-a-theano-model-built-on-gpu-to-cpu), I set the option `config.experimental.unpickle_gpu_on_cpu` to `True`.

But then I got this error:

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> f = open('results/model.save')
>>> cPickle.load(f)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py:541: UserWarning: config.experimental.unpickle_gpu_on_cpu is set to True. Unpickling CudaNdarray as numpy.ndarray
warnings.warn("config.experimental.unpickle_gpu_on_cpu is set to True. Unpickling CudaNdarray as numpy.ndarray")
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/opt.py", line 2192, in <module>
     import theano.sandbox.cuda.extra_ops
   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/extra_ops.py", line 424, in <module>
     @register_gpu_opt()
  NameError: name 'register_gpu_opt' is not defined
```

The `model.save` file was produced the following way:

```
import cPickle
f = file('results/model.save', 'wb')
model_soft_predict = theano.function([x], layer3.p_y_given_x)
cPickle.dump(model_soft_predict, f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
f.close()
```

Comment: Doesn't address the GPU->CPU issue but a bit more, expanding on lyoncao's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921084/how-to-save-serialize-a-trained-model-in-theano/31922453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a typical problem.
Why does it happen? Because theano compiles the model into c/cuda c codes, so an error will happen when the model finds  codes from inconsistent compiler.

How to handler is problem? I would choose to save all the parameters as numpy value. For example

```
values_to_pickle = [p.get_value() for p in model.all_parameters()]
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach makes a lot of sense to me. However it means I have to implement export/import-parameters methods in each layer of my network... Or is there a smarter way?

Comment: My solution for your consideration: Every layer needs to know the list of its parameters. Then for a list of layer (denoted as a var  "layers") we can define a global function get_all_parameters(layers) and set_all_parameters(layers). For any model with multiple layers, we can call parameters = get_all_parameters(self.layers) and pickle parameters to/from disk. no need to implement save_parameter or load_parameter for every layer.